# Trying to add data to sql from link click and return results via jquery or ajax

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am not familiar with jquery or ajax, but i do know it is whats needed to perform the action I want. I have created a wordpress plugin that updates a database table based on the users click. Right now it refreshes the page to return the results, but I want to stop the page refresh and return data via ajax I believe. If anyone is interested in helping me figure this out I would be very appreciative or even willing to pay.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you show us some code/test page..and maybe what have you tried so far?

Comment: hah! SO should implement a "donate" button next to each answer...

Comment: I would be more than happy to donate

Comment: please [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42767/edit-out-an-offer-of-financial-reward-right-or-wrong) and if you want your question to get answered add some code and explain what you have ACTUALLY done! and if you are actually looking for a freelancer then this is not the place for it!

Comment: What I have ACTUALLY done is writting the php for the plugin. As I said I know nothing about jquery/ajax. If asking for help on something I know nothing about is wrong...then I guess I came to the wrong place. Since I have asked in other places and had no responses, I mentioned being willing to donate or pay (as jondavidjohn) made the comment above. If thats what your angry about, then I apologize and guess I came to the wrong place for help

Comment: @Jay - don't get me wrong, I'm not angry at all, but look at your question..you didn't provide any starters to get help! for example have you looked at [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), at the external resources there's an article that explains how this would work, [this](http://ocaoimh.ie/make-your-wordpress-plugin-talk-ajax/) in particular, check point 5..really it's not hard at all. But really without any code or markup how could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You said you've written some PHP. This does the actual databse update I hope?

Add to this script so it also echoes whatever data you need to update the page.  (If its more involved than plain text you might need to look into JSON or something else)

jQuery has convenient functions for ajax.  You said you're using jQuery already right?  http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

`$.load` is the simplest if all you need to do is update a single element of the page to the ajax response.  If you need to do more check out `$.get` `$.post` or `$.ajax`

```
$('#ajaxresponse').load('urlofscript.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I need to do, based on my php I added above, is when a user clicks on "Like" it updates the database (as the php above does) and returns that they like it (which the php above does), except that my script refreshes the page to do this.

Comment: so would I then just change the div id to ajaxresponse and the .load would be the url of my php file. Or would I need to seperate and create 2 php files?

Comment: you're probably going to have many of these like buttons, so i suppose maybe a class for all like buttons and an id for this one.  (this id is probably already going to php script/database)

Comment: the plugin is inserted into a loop, so the php script above generates the link (button). I just need to beable to update the "like" after clicked without refreshing the page

Comment: is it better or needed to have the return script in a different php file? Or I should say output?